# Propagate exit code using ssh -J

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I would like to know if there is a way to get the result code of a remote command over ssh when using the `-J` option.

> `-J destination`: Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host described by destination and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.

It is trivial to get it in a normal session:

```sh
ssh -T user@server.example.com <<< "exit 42"
echo $? # output: 42
```

But I'm not able to get it here:

```sh
ssh -T -J user@proxy.example.com user@server.example.com <<< "exit 42"
echo $? # output: 0
```

I would like to get 42 even in the second request. Thank you.

Comment: This seems like a bug in OpenSSH. I suspect it's because the jumphost tunnel gets closed after the final-destination tunnel, so the final exit status comes from the jumphost connection rather than the final destination (the one you care about). Not sure how to get around it, though. I suppose you could `echo $?` as the last thing in the remote command, and capture that, but that's pretty klugy.

Comment: On Linux mint/19 (openssh_7.6p1) it works as expected. Check with `ssh -T -j localhost localhost ...`. It might be a problem with older version of ssh on the proxy server.

Comment: @dash-o Doing `ssh -T -J user@proxy.example.com user@proxy.example.com <<< "exit 42"` works as expected but both the proxy and the server version (`ssh -V`) are the same `OpenSSH_7.2p2`! So it doesn't make sense why it's not working.